# Why PayPal signup is required in a credit card payment

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal express checkout in a mobile website. When a user uses the credit card payment and has entered the credit card information, the billing info page is opened. On this page there is a form: "Create a Personal Account (required)". Why is the PayPal signup required with a credit card payment?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that guest checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction. PayPal runs a risk check to determine eligibility for guest checkout. There will be times when guest checkout is not available. This is intended. Here are a few things to make sure guest checkout is offered as often as possible.

- Verified PayPal account
- Confirmed email address
- Guest Checkout enabled
- With Express Checkout your cart must pass "SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole"

If all of these are met and it's not available then our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons. This is not a permanent decision and it will be available in the future.

Express Checkout was never intended to function as a sole solution for merchants. It was meant specifically to process PayPal payments.

Comment: Thanks. All of the above points are met. If I do the checkout process on my desktop computer, it works ok and does not require creating account. But if I use my mobile phone browser, account creation is required.

Comment: Sounds like for some reason PayPal has identified the mobile transaction as riskier than the desktop one. PayPal's risk assessment is a black box, even to the non-risk-assessment PayPal staff, both because PayPal isn't eager to have people trying to game it and because it's ridiculously complex and constantly evolving so any answer that could be given would be useless going forward anyway. THe decision might be due (in part) to the mobile platform (lacking support for a security feature), the network or IP address (and it's history), the physical device (and it's history), or who knows what.

Comment: This is not good, because we want to provide an easy one-time credit card purchase on a mobile website. Any good alternatives to PayPal?

Comment: @Thivakaran mentioned the SOLUTIONTYPE parameter, but there are a couple more I would make sure you include to see if it works for you.  The three together have always worked for me as long as the locale code isn't set to a country that isn't compatible:  SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing&USERSELECETEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard.  You also need to make sure you're using the latest API version.